# Issue with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have gone through the proper protocol with Heroku, installed the gem puma, created a Procfile, and have successfully implemented the git push heroku master command. But when I opt to initiate Heroku open, the website will not display my app. I ran Heroku logs --tail, and the error comes up that the app crashed. When I ran Heroku run rake db:migrate, this message came up:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on stormy-tor-8615... up, run.9976
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

Is this indicative that my app's models were successfully migrated? If not, how can I properly troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: What does `heroku logs` show before the crash?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I will suggest you check if you are still on a feature branch locally. if you are, you may want to push that branch instead. you can do that by typing git push heroku master:(your branch name)

Comment: Thank you for replying :)I originally pushed the app from master. Do you think it's an issue with postgres?

Comment: Please did you add rails_12factor gem? If not add them gem. Do bundle install and try again.

Comment: The rails_12factor has been added to the production group in the gem file, and I ran bundle install. When I attempted to migrate the database to Heroku, and then proceed with Heroku Open, the application was still blocked from being feature on the site.

Comment: 2015-11-12T00:43:34.784224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stormy-tor-8615.herokuapp.com request_id=1417094f-1bc5-4a46-96ef-83877ce4b24c " dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: hmmm my other suggestion would be that you check if the db.yml file has postgresql set as the adapter.

Comment: I checked and postgresql is currently set as the adapter. Do you think the app deployment is contingent upon the current status of the app's models? I recently added a devise user_admin account model, and have migrated it, but I'm still in the process of properly configuring it to used with the Devise User model. Do you think that's its blocking the app from featuring on Heroku?

Comment: I do have postgresql as the adapter. When I went to run the command: Heroku run rake db:reset, I received this error:

Comment: heroku run rake db:reset
Running rake db:reset on stormy-tor-8615... up, run.1638
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the problems with my app, it turned out that the spec file was duplicated in the app directory, and once I removed it, I then directed my attention to the config/secrets.yml, where the residing issue was how I initially setup the secret_key_base ENV hash. There was a slight error in the original entry, which in retrospect, broke the app when I attempted to push it to Heroku. After I correctly reconfigured the ENV hash, the app was able to be accessed via Heroku. And, then I was able to manually input the Facebook App id and APP secret key via the terminal.